# Allow users to upload and display multiple photos

Tags: images, gallery

So basically I have a social website and I want for Wordpress users to be able to upload pictures and display them on their front end profile page.

I have been looking into the user submitted galleries, but all of them put user pictures into one gallery.

I need them to be similar to facebook, where each user's uploaded photos will be displayed only on their profile pages.

And only them could upload/edit/delete their photos.

I know it may take a lot of time to code this, but if anyone have a piece of code, or can suggest a plugin that does this, I would gladly appreciate.

Comment: I've written stuff where I allow users to upload a profile photo that gets assigned to a group or that gets assigned directly to their user id... ...but it's pretty expansive code and I can't just post the entire thing here.  I'd recommend you start first by making the profile page where the user can upload these things, include a 'form' for the user to upload their photo and then tackle that process first.  It's impossible to answer this question correctly, so tackle it step by step.  Step 1 would be - let the user upload their image and save it to '?'..

Comment: okey thanks. I thought it won't be a short code for this. It's not urgent, so I will try figure things out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution in the front-end or in the admin interface?

If you're looking for something in the admin interface, the following [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-restrict-media-library-access-to-users-own-uploads-in-wordpress/) should help you out for limiting the access to the user which uploaded the image.

If you're looking for something in the frontend, maybe [this](https://www.blogtyrant.com/allow-users-upload-images-to-wordpress/) should help you a step forward.